Problems displaying pivot charts in E4 RCP
here is the application.e4xmi：

This is how the Perspective looks when start:

In Open Perspective Dialog:

So Strange
The display is normal when using extension point definitions, but incorrect when using Application.e4xmi

The <> around the name is because the old style perspective handling doesn't know about perspectives added directly to the e4xmi and thinks this is an 'orphan' perspective - one where the extension point definition is no longer present (the code that does this is WorkbenchPage.fixOrphanPerspective)
So basically you can't really use perspectives added directly to the e4xmi when you are also using 3.x compatability code as well. Stick to extension points for the perspectives.
